# Java Key Press Event

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a Bengali Keyboard using Java Swing. I am accessing key press event and replacing a particular character with relevant Bengali character. The problem I am getting is the original English character is still appending at the end. How to stop it? Here is the code.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
if(e.getKeyCode() == 54)
{
    textField.setText(textField.getText()+(char)2433);
}
if(e.getKeyCode() == 65)
{
    textField.setText(textField.getText()+(char)2438);
}
}
```

The output is coming like "আa", should be only "আ".

Thanks in advance.

Here is the full Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Phonetic extends JFrame
{
    public Phonetic() 
    {
        setTitle("AntaryƒÅmƒ´");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Mukti Narrow", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        textField.setBounds(12, 33, 614, 383);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
                @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 54)
            {
                textField.setText(textField.getText()+(char)2433);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 65)
            {
                textField.setText(textField.getText()+(char)2438);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
        {
        }
    });

    this.setSize(650, 450);
    this.show();
}
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField textField;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Phonetic();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a KeyListener.

Instead use a `DocumentFilter`. As text is inserted into the text field the DocumentFilter is invoked. At this time you should translate the typed character to the character that you want to insert into the Document and then invoke the super method. You will need to override both the insertString() and replace() methods.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information and an example to get your started.

Comment: This sounds good reasoning. This method may work. But can you give more pointers. Thanks.

Comment: *"But can you give more pointers"*  I'm not the author of this answer, but I have a pointer for you.  Go through the linked tutorial.  Ask a more specific question if there is anything you do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
textField.setText((char)2433);
```

`textField.getText()+(char)2433` appends the existing content of the `TextField` to the new character.

---

Edit in response to OP's comment:

It's more efficient to translate the user input on an event like a button click. Cause you'll confuse the user if as he/she enters a single letter you convert it to Bengali.

I mean you can wait until the user completes the word, then show the result, and if you need a real time translation (if we can call it so), a better option is to have a separate `TextField` and there you should say

```
translateTextField.setText(translateTextField.getText()+(char)2438);
```

while the event is raised on key press in the original `TextField`. I hope this is clear.

If you want to edit the code in place, try this: (Suppose `convert` is a method that converts all the string (s) and the character (e) and concatenate them)

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    s = textField.getText();
    textField.setText(convert(s, e.getKeyCode));
}
```

Comment: What if he wants to preserve the previous content of `TextField`?

Comment: But then again he will have to add content of that variable with `(char) 2433`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right. But Its a notepad kind of interface. So an user will input multiple characters to make a word. So I have to have append method for this.

Comment: Tried the following one too, but not working......
   String text=textField.getText();
   text+=(char)2438);
   textField.setText(text);

Comment: @mok: Yes I can develop a clickable keyboard, but that is an inefficient way to type. My target is to make a phonetic keyboard.

Comment: @user3550680> I say it's just confusing to translate (convert) in place.

Comment: @Mok: See this one. I want to generate a similar one with Swing.http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/bengali.htm. It is not confusing. It is more efficient typing process. I edited the full code. Please have look and let me know.

Comment: @Mok: Thanks. but I tried that one also. Doesn't work! I tried other king of String operations as well, but the original char is always appending.

Comment: @user3550680> You're welcome, I got it. please note to the edit.

Comment: not working! Actually I guess this one too. The original character is added not from here from other super class I guess. So this method I tried in a different way.....not working.....

Comment: @user3550680> haha, ok. so there is a safe,reliable and inefficient approach, every time convert all the text and put it to the `TextField`.

Comment: @Mok: Absolutely. When I started I though its easy thing....but it seems harder!! I want a on-the-fly solution, I can not go for post-modification. The reason is that if one input "j" result will be different but if people press "jh" the result will be different.

Comment: @user3550680> No, it's at least the easy part. So just keep the original text always and convert it every time not the content of the text field. For sure there is no way to guess what the user will insert in future (ja,jb,jc,jd,...,jz).

Comment: `If you want to edit the code in place,` - then use a DocumentListener. It was designed to do exactly this. Don't use a KeyListener. That is an old approach for AWT. Swing has newer and better API's.

Comment: @camickr> Thanks for your valuable comment.